# Understanding the ending of Lapvona

Tags: religion, ottessa-moshfegh, lapvona

These are few lines from the ending of *Lapvona* written by Ottessa Moshfegh:

> Marek was nearly at the top of the mountain. He was surprised by his own strength and endurance. While the baby had at first sapped him of energy, it seemed now to drive him powerfully to reach the top of the cliff. He held it against his heart and scanned the ground, as though looking for his old footprints, but he found none. Then, in the branches of a forsythia bush, he saw Jacob’s old bow, and further still, at the top of the cliff, Jacob himself. It was not his ghost or his grave, but his skeleton. The bones were pure
> white, lying in a pile. The skull was missing. Marek assumed it had rolled off the cliff, or a vulture had wrenched it off and dropped it somewhere to enjoy it in private. Jude had left the body there as a sacrifice, Marek assumed. He must have felt it would please God.
> The baby turned inside Marek’s jacket. He looked down at its face and held it tightly. It was true that the baby was something very valuable. Anyone would be completely hypnotized by its beauty. It was so perfect and small. It would be easy to throw it. Marek unbuttoned his jacket and pulled the baby out into the sunshine. It smiled and reached its hands toward its brother’s face.
> ‘Don’t worry,’ Marek said. ‘Death is not the end. You shall rise. What are the birds but angels? You will never have to walk among the monsters. It’s much better up there. You’ll see, you’ll see. You will be so happy and free, you’ll sing.’

Does the ending further the interpretation of killing the limelight, the incarnation of Jesus Christ and snapping the religious beliefs the town was tethered to?

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing this - happy to let it stand with improvements, especially given it has an upvote, but just so you know the preferred approach is to edit ypu existing question after which it can attract reopen votes.

Comment: @MattThrower Noted.

Comment: Sadly, "do you support Marek's actions" is still opinion-based. Please [edit this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/26483/edit) so that it asks what evidence there is in the novel to show whether or not Marek's actions are justified. You could also ask how critics or scholars have interpreted the ending. But asking for what people here *think*, rather than for an answer that relies on objective analysis or the novel's reception, puts the question [in danger of being closed again](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/916/289).